# How can I setup a multi-domain under one Craft CMS

Tags: apache, multi-domain

I would like to ask how can I setup a multi-domain under one Craft CMS.

I have created a default website (ex: coffee.com) that is running and no problem but I want another site with a different domain.
I already created another domain (ex: beer.com) using Plesk but I don't know how I can connect it to the main craft CMS because right now it only shows the Plesk landing page.

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Plesk, make sure that the DocumentRoot of the beer.com domain is the same as the DocumentRoot of the coffe.com domain
- In Craft, create an other site having `beer.com` as its **Base URL**

Comment: Thank you. It works!!!